# Main() method only executed when a request comes in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 web app.

I noticed if I run it using the project name, `DutchTreat`, the breakpoint in my `Main()` method is hit immediately.

However if I run using IIS Express, the `Main()` method's breakpoint only gets hit when I initiate an HTTP request.

[image]

Why is this?

What code is actually running when I start the app using IIS Express but before I make an HTTP request?

[image]

Also, why does IIS Express use completely different port numbers for HTTP and HTTPS, whereas when using the project name, it uses 5000 and 5001?

IIS:

[image]

Project name:

[image]

Comment: IIS and IIS Express only setup the listener so they can receive requests. I'm not sure whether it uses Windows Process Activation Service,  http.sys or something else to achieve this. As a result it only starts your process (or loads an app domain) when a request comes in. This is great for start-up time of IIS (Express) but your first visitor takes the penalty for having to load the Framework and do its setup thing before it starts to handle the actual request.

Comment: @rene Lazy loading of ASP.NET Core web apps (calling `Main` when first request comes) is implemented inside ASP.NET Core module (part of the Windows Hosting bundle), so not IIS/IIS Express. There is another layer of lazy loading (initializing w3wp.exe for IIS application pools) which uses Windows Process Activation Service, but that's only used by IIS (as it has application pools) not by IIS Express (which is a single process server).

Comment: For a web app, this is the expected behavior. If you want your app running all the time, then you need to configure your host to be always on, but if you want your program always on then a web project is not the best start point.

Answer (score 2):

For Asp.net core, there is a self-hosted application named Kestrel. It's a web server that handles requests/responses.
In this case, IIS/IISExpress acts as a proxy and application activator.

If you start your web application by running your app (`DutchTreat`) directly, the Kestrel server is started (`Main()` runs) and listens for HTTP requests.
Otherwise, if you run your app with IIS/IISExpress, IIS will add a reference to the application (`UrlRewrite` in web.config). When an HTTP request comes, IIS will trigger the running of your application (.exe) and then the `Main()` method will be executed.

Comment: Where is the web.config file you mentioned? I thought that was replaced with appsettings.json in .NET Core and .NET 5?

Comment: Yes, you're right. For .NET core, `appsettings.json` is file that contains application configurations . In .NET Framework,  `web.config` file contains two kind of configurations, one for IIS and the other for web application. When you run your .NET 5 application in IISExpress, there is config file is generated in `.vs\<Project>\config\applicationhost.config`. In this file, you will see a section `AspNetCoreModuleV2`, this module will control your application.

Comment: “IIS will add a reference to the application (UrlRewrite in web.config)” is incorrect. If you use `dotnet new` to generate a new web project and deploy to IIS, there is nothing called "UrlRewrite" in web.config. And that's also not called "a reference", and is not added by IIS but your ASP.NET Core template. Another incorrect piece is that "IIS will trigger the running of your application (.exe)" is only valid when the ASP.NET Core app is hosted in out-of-process mode. When hosting in in-process mode, everything runs inside `w3wp.exe` or `iisexpress.exe`